# The meaning and usage of "видать"

Tags: словоупотребление

> Смотрю на них, думаю, **видать** не у одной меня порой крыша едет!

Given the context, I assume the sentence means:

> It is not just me who loses it every now and then -- such outbursts of temper are **seen** not just in me.

But I'm not sure how to interpret its grammatical function and infinitive usage. Can the sentence stand without "видать"? If so, what meaning/nuance does "видать" add to the sentence?

> Смотрю на них, думаю, не у одной меня порой крыша едет!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a colloquial form of "**видимо**" or "**по-видимому**" and it's translated as "[it] seems like".
So the sentence is roughly translated as "I look at them and it seems like I'm not the only one [who's] losing it".

Answer (score 5):

Totally agree with AR's answer.
But will only add that in my opinion a semantically closer English equivalent is **`looks like`** due to relatedness of both verbs **`видеть/видать`** and **`to look`** to the notion of sight.

Thus

> I look at them and think to myself: 'It **looks like** i'm not the only
>   one going crazy every now and then!'

And of course the sentence can go without **`видать`** because it's just a speaker's remark.